# Update ExtendToCustomerPXExt / Location fields

Tags: acumatica

I would like update the cTaxZoneID fields with the ExtendToCustomer process :

```
  public virtual IEnumerable ExtendToCustomerPXExt(PXAdapter adapter)
  {
try { //App_Data\CodeRepository\PX.Objects\Extensions\ExtendBAccount
                var graphExt = Base.GetExtension<ExtendToCustomer>();
                if (graphExt.extendToCustomer.GetEnabled()) { graphExt.extendToCustomer.Press(); }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                if (ex is PXRedirectRequiredException) {
                    PXRedirectRequiredException nvgraph = (PXRedirectRequiredException)ex;

                    // If there is a need to make changes in new Graph
                    CustomerMaint editCustomer = (CustomerMaint) nvgraph.Graph;
                    editCustomer.BAccount.Current.CustomerClassID = "FAMA" ;
                    editCustomer.BAccount.View.Answer = WebDialogResult.Yes;
                    editCustomer.BaseLocations.Current.CTaxZoneID = "NEWTAXE";
```

I tried too

```
PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location un_location = PXSelect<CRLocation, Where<CRLocation.locationID, Equal<Required<CRLocation.locationID>>>>.Select(Base, editCustomer.BAccount.Current.DefLocationID);
un_location.CTaxZoneID = "NEWTAXE";
Base.Caches[typeof(PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location)].MarkUpdated(un_location);
```

[image]

Comment: Could you further clarify the behavior you would like to see? Currently when a Vendor is extended to customer the record is not persisted until the save button is pressed by the user which would allow you to make modifications to the TaxZoneID for the "new" customer record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work was completed within 23R2 :

With this customization code you are able to change the `CTaxZoneID` of the newly created customer during the "Extend to Customer" vendor process.

```
//2nd level Graph Extension to override functionality found within ExtendToCustomerGraph 1st level Graph Extension
public class AAExtendToCustomerExtension : PXGraphExtension<ExtendToCustomer, VendorMaint>
{

    //Override of "Extend" method found within ExtendToCustomerGraph
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual CustomerMaint Extend(Func<CustomerMaint> del)
    {
        //Returns graph with "new" customer within Cache from base method call.
        CustomerMaint customerMaint = del?.Invoke();

        //Initilize Graph Extension pertaining to Location logic and values.
        CustomerMaint.DefLocationExt customerMaintExtension = customerMaint.GetExtension<CustomerMaint.DefLocationExt>();

        //Retrieve current location record of "new" customer.
        PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location location = customerMaintExtension.DefLocation.Select();

        //Set CTaxZoneID
        location.CTaxZoneID = "WASTATE";

        //Update record within the cache
        customerMaintExtension.DefLocation.Update(location);

        //Return graph with modified location record back to Acumatica method.
        return customerMaint;
    }
}
```